# Capture Scrolling Action in UITextView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiscrollview, scrollview

I would like to be able to store the scroll position of a UITextView. I would like to bind this against an AppController property so that other tab pages can make use of it.

I can set and get ContentOffset value, but I think I need to be informed of a scrolling event to update the property. How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so you can implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidScroll:` in the view's delegate.